How can I use InternalsVisibleTo for prefix case in Visual Studio for C# internal class?
I have two projects: TestA project config:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
            <_Parameter1>$(MSBuildProjectName).Abca</_Parameter1>
        </AssemblyAttribute>
        <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
            <_Parameter1>$(AssemblyName).Abca</_Parameter1>
        </AssemblyAttribute>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And the code is:
namespace TestA
{
    internal class MyClass
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
        }
    }
}

"TestB" project config:
namespace Test.Abca
{
    using TestA;

    internal class Class1
    {
        internal void Foo()
        {
             MyClass myClass = new MyClass();   
        }
    }
}

I added the TestA reference to Test.Abca but got an error when using the code:

Error CS0122: 'MyClass' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I tried improving the InternalsVisibleTo setting to various types but it didn't work, it only worked when sure with the name "Test.Abca". This is something I do not want.
What I want is to be used for many projects named like "Test.***".

InternalsVisibleTo don't work with wildcards

Depending on your project namespaces, you may have to tweak this a bit, but with a little addition to your csproj file(s) you can automatically handle this as desired. You can also do this as a Directory.Build.targets file.
The primary is:
<ItemGroup Condition="@(InternalsVisibleToSuffix->Count()) == 0 AND @(InternalsVisibleTo->Count()) == 0">
    <InternalsVisibleToSuffix Include=".Tests" />
</ItemGroup>

Here is a fully put together example that I've used in the past.
<Project>
    <Target Name="AddInternalsVisibleTo" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
        <ItemGroup Condition="@(InternalsVisibleToSuffix->Count()) == 0 AND @(InternalsVisibleTo->Count()) == 0">
            <InternalsVisibleToSuffix Include=".Tests" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup Condition="'@(InternalsVisibleTo->Count())' &gt; 0">
            <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
                <_Parameter1>%(InternalsVisibleTo.Identity)</_Parameter1>
            </AssemblyAttribute>
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup Condition="@(InternalsVisibleToSuffix->Count()) &gt; 0">
            <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
                <_Parameter1>$(AssemblyName)%(InternalsVisibleToSuffix.Identity)</_Parameter1>
            </AssemblyAttribute>
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
                <_Parameter1>DynamicProxyGenAssembly2</_Parameter1>
            </AssemblyAttribute>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>

This was built upon the blog I found at www.meziantou.net

Thank you very much, but I added it but it doesn't work.

@TOAN-VN did you tweak it to match your namespace pattern(s)? It definitely works. I use it on several projects. The example I provided is expecting your test projects to have a suffix of MyProject.Tests and the project under test to be MyProject. If that's not your pattern, then adjust as appropriate.
